# Theory of relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, relativity

I am totally confused about the [theory of relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_relativity). Can someone please explain this, so that I can understand this theory?

Comment: Could you please say a little bit about the texts you are using, what level your course is and some idea of the issues you are running aground on? It's very hard to help you without further description. Given you've used both the SR and GR tags, I'd suggest concentrating on one particular topic from special relativity that is confusing you, and ask as specific a question as you can about that.

Comment: GR is not some collection of objective facts which can be stated so that one understands the theory...If you want to START off, I'd suggest Hartle or Schutz....In case you have difficulties with a particular topic, please let us know in detail so that there is no ambiguity

Comment: Special relativity would be a term long course during a physics degree. General relativity wouldn't be taught until the last year or a postgraduate course. No satisfactory explanation can be given in a single answer here. For good books to learn relativity see our [book recommendations](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations).

Comment: I  am just an engineering student and physics is my favoirite subject.

Comment: If you want to get an answer, understand it in 5 minutes and then think you understand at least the special relativity, it won't go. You have to learn. If you are an engineering student, here is an online course on the MIT: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-20-introduction-to-special-relativity-january-iap-2005/index.htm , or a more easy link here: http://conduit9sr.tripod.com/

Comment: Sorry, can't help you. The theory of relativity has been put on hold.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, someone can explain it, and his name is Albert Einstein!

After publishing the formal scientific papers (Special and General theory) he wrote a book with very little mathematics. I can thoroughily recomend this book because it is the one I read many years ago which gave me an understanding of this fascinating subject. The chapter on the train is a very clear illustration of why we cannot have unique simultaneity, and time.
I have just checked on the internet and this book is still available. The title is "Relativity: the Special and Genetal theory" by Albert Einstein.

Comment: Indeed, it's an excellent book to start with. The book was written by A.Einstein in German and translated in English by R.W.Lawson. As written under its title it's _A Popular Exposition by ALBERT EINSTEIN_. The Preface of the book signed by the Author has date _December 1916_ , exactly a century ago.

Comment: "Relativity: the Special and Genetal theory" . What a strange title.

Comment: Oops sorry Sean. A freudian slip!